# Disable the underlying window when a popup is created in Python TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a master Frame (call it `a`), and a popup Toplevel (call it `b`). How do I make sure the user cannot click on anything in `a` while `b` is "alive"?

Comment: I see there is an answer but it is non-blocking in a technical sense, though it prevents the GUI from being used. If you intend to pause execution (make code after sub-window creation not run until sub-window is closed) as well, use root.wait_window(another_toplevel) as demonstrated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437342/pause-execution-until-user-input-received-from-tkinter-window

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you don't want to hide the root but just make sure the user can only interact with the popup, you can use [`grab_set()` and `grab_release()`](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-gui-programming/9781788835886/4ed5ade9-49fa-42a3-82d4-51267b30ac83.xhtml).

Example app, tested with Python 3.7 and 3.8:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import platform


class Popup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tl = None
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Grab Set/Release")

        tk.Label(self.root, text=f"Python v{platform.python_version()}").pack(padx=12, pady=12)
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Popup!", width=20, command=self.popup).pack(padx=12, pady=12)
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit", width=20, command=sys.exit).pack(padx=12, pady=12)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def popup(self):
        if self.tl is None:
            self.tl = tk.Toplevel()
            tk.Button(self.tl, text="Grab set", width=20, command=self.lock).pack(padx=12, pady=12)
            tk.Button(self.tl, text="Grab release", width=20, command=self.unlock).pack(padx=12, pady=12)

    def lock(self):
        self.tl.grab_set()
        print("Grab set!")

    def unlock(self):
        self.tl.grab_release()
        print("Grab released!")


Popup()
```

**Alternatively**, you could `withdraw()` the root to make it invisible:

```
root.withdraw()
```

will leave the root alive, but only `b` visible.

If you need it back, you can do

```
root.deiconify()
```

Comment: Just to add to your answer, I found the documentation on this (after a bit of digging) here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Comment: In most cases, `grab_release()` isn't necessary. If `grab_set()` is used on a window, control is automatically released when the window is closed.

Comment: Is it possible to gray out the background window? (Without graying our each component individually)

Comment: Is first one (`grab_set()`) still working on latest tkinter and Python 3.7.9? These functions doesn't effects.

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan: Yes it should still work in Python 3.7 and up. Expanded the example with working code. If you run it, you will find that you can't interact with the root window when "grab_set" is called from the popup window.