# Pause execution until user input received from tkinter window

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm trying to do something that on the surface seem like it should be simple.

I'm executing a series of operations in Python such that one must complete before the next begins:

```
operation1()
operation2()
operation3()
```

However, `operation2()` requires user input from a tkinter Entry box in a popup window. Once I create this popup, `operation3()` executes. How do I prevent this? `operation2()` can create the popup and enter an indefinite loop, but a button in the popup must run a function that will break that loop. What's the best way to do this? It is important that `operation2()` has finished before `operation3()` begins.

Apologies if I'm not being clear, but I've completely confused myself trying to make this work!!!

Comment: You should make your popup modal

[How to create a modal dialog in tkinter?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803686/how-to-create-a-modal-dialog-in-tkinter

Comment: Why not include `operation3()` in the button's callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to make your main window (the `root`) wait for the popup window to run it's course.

This is accomplished by creating a popup as normal (using a `Toplevel()` widget I would assume), and then calling `root.wait_window(theToplevel)`.

I've created a small example of how this is done, I think it should give you the idea.

Essentially it prompts you for an `int`. A popup appears upon success (call it `operation 2`) which prompts you for another `int`. After `operation 2` completes, the command of the `OK` button of the main window changes to `operation 3`, which will destroy the window. However, I could also simply call `op3` after the call to `root.wait_window(new)`; this would destroy the main window once the popup finishes (or whatever `op3` should do).

I've also included a for loop that simply prints a range; this is to illustrate that *nothing* will continue until the `Toplevel` has finished collecting it's data.

Here's the example code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
root = Tk()
val = 0
val2 = 0

def op1():

    global e, l, root, val, e2, b, new
    try:
        val = int(e.get())
    except ValueError:
        showerror("Error", "Enter an int")
    else:
        new = Toplevel()
        e2 = Entry(new)
        e2.pack(side = LEFT)
        b2 = Button(new, text = "OK", command = op2)
        b2.pack(side = RIGHT)
        l2 = Label(new, text = "Enter new number to multiply %d by" %val)
        l2.pack()
        e2.focus_force()
        root.wait_window(new)
        for i in range(5):
            print (i + 1)

def op2():
    global val
    try:
        val2 = int(e2.get())
    except ValueError:
        showerror("Error", "Enter an int")
        e2.focus_force()
    else:
        val = val * val2
        l.config(text = "This is your total: %d Click OK to exit" %val)
        new.destroy()
        b.config(command = op3)
def op3():
    root.destroy()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack(side = LEFT)
b = Button(root, text = "OK", command = op1)
b.pack(side = RIGHT)
l = Label(root, text = "Enter a number")
l.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: How would I do this without using a pop-up window for the entry? Suppose the entry is in the main window and I want the focus to lock on the entry box until something is entered?

Comment: @Shihab Dider There's more than one solution to this, but one way is to disable other widgets until a valid result is detected in the entry box. I would suggest making a question so you can try find an answer tailored to your situation, as this is quite different from the question being asked.