# Using windows forms in Python how to change starting position of messagebox

Tags: python, winforms, clr, messagebox

I am using a python install that doesn't accept Tkinter or any other gui library but will accept .Net and windows forms. I have a message box that needs to come on screen to give the user a message but it always comes up dead centre of the monitor. As the user needs to interact with the window directly underneath the message box the user needs to grab the message box and drag it to another part of the screen before interacting with the window underneath and then pressing ok on the message box. Is there any other way to set the message box to appear in a corner of the monitor or elsewhere?

EDIT: I have a form now, but still don't know the method to call to position the window elsewhere than centre.

**Initial Code**

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
import System.Windows.Forms as WF


WF.MessageBox.Show("Message box in centre ")
```

**Newer code - still doesn't get me a window in the corner**

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python24\Lib')

import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")

from System.Drawing import Point
from System.Windows.Forms import Application, Button, Form, Label

class SdnMessageForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Text = 'SDN winform'

        self.label = Label()
        self.label.Text = "Move drops to datum"
        self.label.Location = Point(50, 50)
        self.label.Height = 30
        self.label.Width = 200
        self.CenterToScreen()
        self.count = 0
 
        button = Button()
        button.Text = "OK"
        button.Location = Point(50, 100)

        button.Click += self.buttonPressed

        self.Controls.Add(self.label)
        self.Controls.Add(button)

    def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
        self.Close()


form = SdnMessageForm()
Application.Run(form)
print(dir(form))
```

**Result**

Creates a message box in the centre of the display

**Desired result**

A message box which is displayed in a corner.

**Acceptable but not desired result**

Comment out the `self.CenterToScreen()` line, this seems to open the form towards the left gof the display, its not custom but its better than I had. I would still appreciate a custom solution where I can position the form on the right upper corner.

Comment: Try making a custom class for tkinter like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833172/how-to-set-the-position-of-a-messagebox-using-tkinter)

Comment: due to a tcl error any time I make a tinter gui or Matplotlib graph it crashes the python install I have. In the version of python I have at work it is being used to make scripts to call C# functions via .Net (or something like that) and throws an error if I run anything with tk, qt, or Matplotlib.

Comment: What tcl error?

Comment: 'TclError : Can't find a useable init.tcl in the following directories...', it's an error that someone at work may take a look at it, its been a known bug for a year. I run scripts that require .Net within the work app, for anything requiring a gui or graph I run them in vs code with no issues. I've just figured out how to make my own form and will update the question.

Comment: Tried re-installing python with tkinter?

Comment: Python comes incorporated into this api, its (I think) something to do with what has control when a gui is running, something that the api wasn't coded for (I just know every attempt to run anything graphical that isn't .net crashes - which is a huge pain).