# How can I customize the placement or position of the text input window in the Turtle module of Python for more precise control?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to move the text input window but cannot figure out how to do it.

```
answer_state = screen.textinput(title="Guess the State", prompt="Enter a U.S state:")
```

Not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: The position is not settable.  If you want more control, you'll need to use something more than a toy language.

Comment: Whats a toy language?

Comment: Turtle.  Turtle is a simple tool designed to teach fundamentals of graphics programming.  It was never intended for real programming, so it doesn't have the facilities for it.

Comment: Python's Turtle module is built on top of the `tkinter` module so there might be a way of doing this with a custom text input window class and setting the window position, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833172/how-to-set-the-position-of-a-messagebox-using-tkinter), but its not a simple solution.  I'm trying to see if its possible, I have my custom text input launching, but not yet at the position I wanted, and I'm throwing an exception when I close it too.  If I get it figured out I'll post an answer.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety : see my answer for code of the custom text input you can use to patch the turtle module and provide the requested functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The textinput function in Turtle does not allow you to change the position.

However, you can create your own using Tkinter with adjustable x and y positions like so:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def create_input_window(x_position, y_position):
    answer_state = ""

    def submit():
        nonlocal answer_state
        answer_state = entry.get()
        root.destroy()

    # Create a tkinter window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Guess the State")

    # Set the position of the tkinter window
    root.geometry(f"+{x_position}+{y_position}")

    # Make the window always stay on top
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

    # Create an entry field and a submit button
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter a U.S. state:")
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)

    # Place the widgets on the tkinter window
    label.pack()
    entry.pack()
    submit_button.pack()

    # Start the tkinter main loop
    root.mainloop()

    return answer_state


# Example usage:
# Call the function to create the input window at a specific position
x_pos = 200
y_pos = 200
result = create_input_window(x_pos, y_pos)
print(f"State entered: {result}")
```

Comment: How does your answer relate to getting  input for use in the Python turtle module?

Comment: I have answered it in the first sentence of the answer; you cannot use Python turtle module to ask for input while specifying the location.

Answer (score -1):

If you are

> Not really sure what to do from here.

I suggest to start with asking yourself following questions:

- *Why do I need/want to customize the placement of an user text input dialog box?*
- *What would be the advantage of moving a text input popup window to a specified position?*
- *What is my actual goal I am after? Why do I think I need customization of input dialog box position to achieve it?*

Answering such questions can be very helpful in finding out that you consider something to be a problem where it actually isn't. Maybe there is a good reason why there is no ready to use solution and why the genuine `screen.textinput()` function of the turtle module does not provide the option for customized positioning of the popup window? The turtle module is not alone here. For example the Python easygui module and the zenity command line tool do not provide such an option, too. Maybe if there is a need of getting user input in order to proceed, the center of the display is the best place for getting user attention?

OK ... if you still mean you really need it, you can write Python code for a customized text input popup window allowing you to control its positioning on the display.

Or you can use, assuming `bash` and `xdotool` are available on your system, a "dirty" trick spawning a delayed execution of a shell command positioning the dialog window at for example x=50 and y=25 just before raising the dialog box:

```
import os
os.system('bash -c "sleep 0.5;xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 50 25" &')
answer=screen.textinput(title="Guess the State", prompt="Enter an U.S. state")
```

Check out further `xdotool` options to target for repositioning only a window with a given title instead of the currently active one to make sure that only the right window can/will be moved to the desired position.

Be warned that the `xdotool` based solution won't work in some edge cases and the window movement will be visible, but ... from my point of view because it excels at brevity and is so straightforward and simple to understand, it is worth to be mentioned.

If you prefer to use a pure Python solution I suggest to patch the turtle module providing the option of custom placing of the dialog box like it is done in the code provided below. This approach utilizes the tkinter module the Turtle module is anyway based on:

```
import turtle

# The PATCH: 
def textinput(self, title="TitleText", prompt="PromptText", geom="+25+25"):
    """ Pop up a user dialog window with given title, prompt and geometry like 
    for example "400x100+25+25" (or "+25+25" only) for input of a text string
    Return user input and if the dialog is canceled, return "---None---". """
    turtle.userInputText = "---None---"
    popupWindow = turtle.TK.Toplevel(self._root) # i.e. screen._root where screen=turtle.Screen()
    popupWindow.geometry(geom) # position and size of the popup window
    popupWindow.title(title)
    turtle.TK.Label(popupWindow, text=prompt).grid(padx=25) # row=0, column=0
    entryBox = turtle.TK.Entry(popupWindow)
    entryBox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=25, pady=15)
    entryBox.focus()
    def getUserInput(event):
        turtle.userInputText = event.widget.get()
        popupWindow.destroy()
    entryBox.bind('<Return>', getUserInput)
    # It is important to place the two lines of code as last ones preceding "return"
    popupWindow.grab_set() # make all user input events go to the popupWindow
    popupWindow.wait_window() # block code flow until the window is closed
    return turtle.userInputText
turtle.TurtleScreenBase.textinput = textinput

# ======================================================================
# The code using the PATCH:
screen=turtle.Screen()
userInput = screen.textinput("Guess the State", "Enter an U.S state:", "+100+100")
turtle.write("userInput: "+userInput+" .", align="center")
turtle.pensize(5); turtle.color("green")
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Please don't quote the complete question. This doesn't make sense, the question is already at the top of the page.  Then `os.system()` is bad and the solution even more. It's fragile because within the sleeping time any other window could get the focus for a number of reasons. This fails if `xdotool` isn't installed.  If fails if this isn't some Linux/Unix with an X server but Wayland for instance. So even under Linux this might not be a solution.

Comment: `Tk` is *the* main window, the Tcl interpreter is associated with that object, there should be just one such object active at any given time or funny things can happen. `Toplevel` is for *additional* top level windows.

Comment: @BlackJack : thanks for your remarks. I have rewritten my answer according to them. Best would be probably to patch the `turtle.py` module to provide this functionality by the by it supported dialog incorporating the provided code into that patch.