# Blocking Input Dialog Box

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, modal-dialog, user-input

How can I get a blocking modal input dialog box in standard Python?

I need the user to input a value before the code can proceed.

Here is some *not-working* test code, but the idea is that I should be able to call `MyDialog` from anywhere in the script, so this is just a simplified example.

```
import tkinter

class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self, prompt):
        self.top = tkinter.Toplevel()
        tkinter.Label(self.top, text=prompt).pack()
        self.e = tkinter.Entry(self.top)
        self.e.pack(padx=5)
        tkinter.Button(self.top, text="OK", command=self.ok).pack(pady=5)

    def ok(self):
        self.top.destroy()
        return self.e.get()


root = tkinter.Tk()
userName = MyDialog('Enter your name')
tkinter.Label(root, text="Hello {}".format(userName)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The dialog should not only disable the master window, but block whatever code called it. And it should be able to pass the value back to the calling code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable the underlying window when a popup is created in Python TKinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363923/disable-the-underlying-window-when-a-popup-is-created-in-python-tkinter)

Comment: @StevenSummers That solution does not provide code blocking.

Comment: Could you clarify on what code would be blocked and what kind of value would be passed back? Such as, if a button opened `MyDialog` then block the button from opening again?

Comment: Line `tkinter.Label(root...` should not get executed until the user has closed the dialog, at which time you will have a user-supplied value in `userName`.

Comment: Can't you create that in the button click event? It seems strange to have it outside the event.

Comment: Do you mean create `userName`? This still would not block the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution requires two critical pieces. First, use `grab_set` to block all events in the other window (or, more correctly, send all events to the dialog window). Second, use `wait_window` to prevent the method from returning until the dialog has been destroyed.

That being said, you shouldn't be using it like in your example. You need to have the `mainloop` running before you create the window. It might work OK on some platforms, but in general you shouldn't expect your GUI to behave properly until `mainloop` is running.

Here's a simple example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyDialog(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, prompt):
        self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        label = tk.Label(self.toplevel, text=prompt)
        entry = tk.Entry(self.toplevel, width=40, textvariable=self.var)
        button = tk.Button(self.toplevel, text="OK", command=self.toplevel.destroy)

        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        button.pack(side="bottom", anchor="e", padx=4, pady=4)

    def show(self):
        self.toplevel.grab_set()
        self.toplevel.wait_window()
        value = self.var.get()
        return value

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Click me!", command=self.on_click)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="", width=40)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    def on_click(self):
        result = MyDialog(self, "Enter your name:").show()
        self.label.configure(text="your result: '%s'" % result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Excellent. I only wish this was already part of `tkinter`, sort of like `tkinter.messagebox`. But this way, it is more customizable.

Comment: @coding4fun: this type of dialog is part of tkinter. It's called [askstring](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm).