# Tkinter Dialog behind borderless window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having problems trying to display a default tkinter askyesno dialog on top of my main window, which has no borders( I am using `overrideredirect(1)` ). Having a borderless window is a must in my case.

The dialog always opens behind the main window. Creating a custom dialog, also borderless seems to work, but I am wandering if there is a way to make the default askYesNo dialog appear on top of a borderless window. I am running the code on Raspbian (a version of Debian).

The python code is attached below:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *

def imageLabelPressed():

    print("Call button pressed")
    selected = lb.get(whichSelected())

    if (askyesno("Call", "Do you want to call %s?" % (selected) )):
        print("Call started")
    else:
        print("Cancel call")

win = Tk()
win.geometry('800x480')

backgroundImg = PhotoImage(file = "background.png")
backgroundLabel = Label(win, image = backgroundImg)
backgroundLabel.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

lb=Listbox(win, height=9)
lb.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

callImage = PhotoImage(file = "callButton.png")
dButt = Label(win, text = "Some text", relief = FLAT, highlightthickness = 0, border = 0, image = callImage)
dButt.bind("<Button-1>", imageLabelPressed)
dButt.pack()

win.overrideredirect(1)
mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: `win.geometry('800x480')` add some x,y  value for free space.

Comment: I want the app to cover the whole screen, so the user can't exit from it ( it will be placed outdoors). The resolution of the screen is 800x480.

Comment: `win.grab_set()` on open dialog, finished job call `win.grab_release()` On base : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363923/disable-the-underlying-window-when-a-popup-is-created-in-python-tkinter (include alternatives)

Comment: "Stack" got a lot similar question and answer. What a `information pollution` ?

Comment: Unfortunately with `win.grab_set()` and `win.grab_release()` the pop up is still under the main window. @dsgdfg I have searched "Stack" and tried solutions suggested but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-window-jump-to-the-front

Comment: if any solution resolve your problem, go to related answer type a answer include your question. My word is `global talk` so not personal(i am sorry if accepted as `personal message` !)

Comment: @BogdanN what kind of problems are you having?
You've said: "I am having problems...", but you have not mentioned the problems you are having.
"Introduce the problem before you post any code

In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."-[Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BogdanN there are some mistakes in your code. For example if you use `bind`, input `event` inside the function which your button returns.

Comment: @BogdanN, secondly, `imageLabelPressed` returns `NameError: name 'whichSelected' is not defined`

Comment: @BogdanN, please solve other problems, and leave only what you are asking us.