# Using Tkinter iwant to open the second window then close the previous one i was on

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

How would I open the second window and close the previous one I was one. So with my code i press ok on the first window it brings me to the second one, but I want the first one to close. I've been struggling for the past 2 hours. thanks

```
from tkinter import *

class Welcome():

 def __init__(self,master):

    self.master= master
    self.master.geometry("1080x800+200+200")
    self.master.title("Sphere Booking and Check-in")

    self.label1=Label(self.master,text="Sphere Booking and Check-in",fg="black",font=("Helvetica",25)).grid(row=0,column=2)
    self.button1=Button(self.master,text="OK",fg="blue",command=self.gotoWages).grid(row=6,column=2)
    self.button2=Button(self.master,text="quit",fg="blue",command=self.finish).grid(row=6,column=3)

def finish(self):

    self.master.destroy()

def gotoWages(self):

    root2=Toplevel(self.master)
    myGUI=Wages(root2)

class Wages():

  def __init__(self,master):

    self.nhours= DoubleVar()
    self.salaryh= DoubleVar()

    self.master= master
    self.master.geometry("1080x800+200+200")
    self.master.title("Sphere Booking and Check-in")

    self.label1=Label(self.master,text="Sphere Booking and Check-in",fg="black",font=("Helvetica",25)).grid(row=0,column=2)
    self.label2=Label(self.master,text="enter your salary per hour").grid(row=3,column=0)
    self.label3=Label(self.master,text="enter the number of hours worked").grid(row=4,column=0)

    self.mysalary= Entry(self.master, textvariable= self.salaryh).grid(row=3, column=3)
    self.mysalary= Entry(self.master, textvariable= self.nhours).grid(row=4, column=3)
    self.button1=Button(self.master,text="OK",fg="blue").grid(row=5,column=3)
    self.button2=Button(self.master,text="quit",fg="blue",command=self.myquit).grid(row=6,column=3)

def myquit(self):
    self.master.destroy()

def main():

  root=Tk()
  myGUIWelcome=Welcome(root)
  root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention is the following post ["Disable the underlying window when a popup is created in Python TKinter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363923/disable-the-underlying-window-when-a-popup-is-created-in-python-tkinter), You have just to add a call to `withdraw()` of your master windows.

```
def gotoWages(self):

    root2=Toplevel(self.master)
    self.master.withdraw() # windows becomes invisible
    myGUI=Wages(root2)
```

**EDIT:** Add the solution to go back to the main window.

To show the main window `class Welcome()` when closing the `class Wages()`, add the call to functions `update()` then `deiconify()` as follow:

**Step1** - store the `Welcome()` handle into the `Wages()`.

In the `Welcome::gotoWages()` function, add the extra parameter `self.master`.

```
myGUI=Wages(root2,self.master)
```

In the `Wages::__init__()` function, manage the extra parameter `mainwnd` and store it.

```
def __init__(self,master,mainwnd):

    self.nhours= DoubleVar()
    self.salaryh= DoubleVar()

    self.mainwnd = mainwnd # store the 'self.master` of the main window
    self.master= master
```

**Step 2** - use the stored `mainwnd` to show the `Welcome` window

Modify the `Wages::myquit()` function:

```
def myquit(self):
    self.master.destroy() # close the current Wages window
    self.mainwnd.update() # update the main window
    self.mainwnd.deiconify() # un-minimize the main window
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and also thanks for the link to the other post!

Comment: To show again the main window, use the functions `update()` then `deiconify()` (see the blog ["Tkinter: How to Show / Hide a Window"](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/26/tkinter-how-to-show-hide-a-window/)).

Comment: so if i want to go back to the window how would i do that? do i need to un-withdraw it?

Comment: Just added in my answer.

Comment: thank you very much. That python blog was really help full as well