# How can I disable my TopLevel window when a message box appears?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code, I have a TopLevel window (the root one has been hided with "withdraw()" method) where, if you do somthing wrong, an error window (created using the "messagebox.showerror()" function) appears. now, how can I disable the TopLevel window to make the user to interact only with the error window?

before to use the "messagebox.showerror()" function I tried to use the "grab_set()" method with my TopLevel window, but it seems doesn't do nothing, maybe because can I use the "grab_set()" method only with the root window? I really don't know how to solve my issue.

Comment: Can't you just withdraw the toplevel window?

Comment: Your question is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15363923/12826372 Good Luck!

Comment: Try setting `master` to the `TopLevel` instance when calling `showerror()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see that my post has been reopened! Anyway, I solved thanks the comment posted by acw1668! To reach my goal, I had to add the "parent" argument in my "messagebox.showerror(..)" instruction. below a template:

```
messagebox.showerror(TITLE, ERROR_MESSAGE, parent = YOUR_WINDOW_OBJECT)
```

By default the parent object is always the root window, but in my case it had to be the TopLevel one.