# grab_set() function not working in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have asked a question previously about the same, here is a link to that: ["Blink" Prompt window if parent window is clicked Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768908/blink-prompt-window-if-parent-window-is-clicked-tkinter)

But it was marked as duplicate. Please help me with my code as I am not able to implement grab_set() in my code even after repeated tries.
I was advised to open a new question, so here it is.

My Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def mainwindow():
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry("100x100")

  b1 = Button(root, text="Exit", command=prompt)
  b1.place(x=50, y=40)
  mainloop()

def prompt():
  pr = Tk()
  pr.geometry("175x100")
  pr.grab_set()

  lable = Label(pr, text="Do you want to exit?").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=15)
  b1 = Button(pr, text="Yes", command=exit).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=75)
  mainloop()

mainwindow()
```

Even after putting `grab_set()` on the `pr` window , I can access the `root` window. Please tell the correct way to put this function inside my code.

Comment: You  should use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` in `prompt()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has some problems like pointed in previous answer (use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` for the second window and use `mainloop` only once) and a few other mores that you should avoid, like importing tkinter twice, creating the root window inside a function in a local variable, or doing `b1 = Button(..).grid(...)`, when the `grid()` method doesn't return anything so `b1 = None`. Beside that, for an exit application prompt, I think you will prefer to use `grab_set_global()`, but as I told you before, you have to be careful with grab since tkinter can only grab a window that has been mapped on the screen, thus you need to use `wait_visibility()` before. Here is an improvement of your code:

```
from tkinter import *

def mainwindow():
    root.geometry("100x100")

    b1 = Button(root, text="Exit", command=prompt)
    b1.place(x=50, y=40)

def prompt():
    pr = Toplevel()
    pr.geometry("175x100")
    pr.wait_visibility()
    pr.grab_set_global()

    label = Label(pr, text="Do you want to exit?").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=15)
    Button(pr, text="Yes", command=exit).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=75)

root = Tk()   
mainwindow()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this on my main code, but I am facing a big issue which i have recorded here: [https://youtu.be/qQyeTmbdqT0] Kindly help me

Comment: ok this is another issue, this solution I gave to you works for the example above, this problem must be related with something else. I may ask you again to create another question with the new issue and give us a bit more of your code so we can reproduce the error you are seeing. I also recommend you to use `show="*"` as property of your password Entry, so no one will be able to see your password when you type it

Comment: Sure, here is the link to the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830567/prompt-opens-infinitely-times-in-tkinter

Comment: Also, about that `show="*"`, I already have that, I just clicked on "Show Password Button" to give a clarity that I am intentionally Entering wrong Password.
Anyways, Thank You soo much for your valuable suggestions & advices :-)

Comment: wait_visibility() helped a lot! Although it is not possible to interact with the window, without this my root was getting on top when I was clicking on it, despite using the function grab_set().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating two root windows (ie: two instances of `Tk`). These instances are separate environments, so any widget in one can't affect or talk to a widget in another.

For a grab to work, all windows need to be under the same root. Your `prompt` function needs to create an instance of `Toplevel` rather than `Tk`. Also, you should not call `mainloop` more than once.