# Prompt opens Infinitely times in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In my previous Question [grab_set() function not working in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797477/grab-set-function-not-working-in-tkinter/), Flavio Moraes suggested me a code.

When I tried to implement it in my main code, I was getting an error which I have recorded here: https://youtu.be/qQyeTmbdqT0

Here is a piece of that code which produces **exactly** the same error:

```
from tkinter import *

def login():
    #ALL GIFs etc.
    top.resizable(0, 0)
    top.title("IDLE for MySQL- Login")
    top.geometry("1080x720")
    submit_button = Button(top,
                           text="Login", fg="#FFFFFF", bd=4, bg="#000000", width=8, font=("Helvetica", 18), command=check).place(
        x=410,
        y=400)
    quit_button = Button(top,
                         text="Quit", fg="#FFFFFF", bd=4, bg="#000000", width=8, font=("Helvetica", 18), command=exit).place(
        x=550,
        y=400)

def check():
    global nlabel, top
    #user = _id.get() [_id = Entry]
    #passw = _p.get() [_p = Entry]
    global mydb, c
    while True:
        try:
            """
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user=user,
                password=passw
            )
            c = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)"""
            raise TypeError #Any error just to produce a "Wrong Password" Effect
        except:
            inc = Toplevel()
            inc.wait_visibility()
            inc.grab_set_global()
            inc.focus_set()
            inc.geometry("300x100")
            msg = Label(inc,
                        text="Incorrect User ID/ Password", font=("Helvetica", 12)).place(
                x=10,
                y=15)
            button1 = Button(inc,
                             text="Ok", bg="#FFFFFF", bd=3, fg="#000000", font=("Helvetica", 18), command=closepop).place(
                x=190,
                y=55)
            button2 = Button(inc,
                             text="Exit", bg="#FFFFFF", bd=3, fg="#000000", font=("Helvetica", 18), command=exit).place(
                x=240,
                y=55)
        else:
            break

def closepop():
    global inc
    inc.grab_release()
    inc.destroy()

top = Tk()
login()
top.mainloop()
```

From what I understand, the problem is that every time the code is checking for the password regardless of any button pressed by the used or not. I even tried butting it in a loop, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Isnt it because of the `while` loop? It's an infinite loop here and keeps on running and at the end it always raises an error? So the except block gets executed, whose windows keep popping up forever since it's a infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, Thank You so much. I am really sorry I am new to Python, so I sometimes do these foolish mistakes.

Comment: @CoolCloud I would suggest you to write that as an answer so I can Accept it and the question closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while True` loop is an infinite loop and inside the loop your raising an error, which will lead to execution of the `except` block, and since your not properly breaking out of the loop, it keeps on happening. Its not clear what your trying to do with the code, but this is the problem. One potential solution is to use `after()` which will repeat the function a given amount time, in ms. Like `root.after(5000,check)`, this will execute `check()` after 5000ms(5 sec).